# whats wrong with the following implementation of bubble sort

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

Here is my implementation of bubble sort why the output doesn't change?Output is same as input vector not the sorted output

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #include<algorithm>


    void bubble_sort(std::vector<int> &v){
        for( int i = 0; i < (v.size() - 1); i++){
            for( int j = 0; j < (v.size() - 1 - i) ; j++){
                if(v[i] < v[i+1]){
                    std::swap(v[i], v[i+1]);
                }
            }
        }

    }


int main(){
    std::vector<int> v = {1,9,8,7,6,5,3,2};
    bubble_sort(v);

    for(auto &e : v){
        std::cout<<e<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wrong parens: if(v[i]) < v[i+1])

Comment: First of all the code you show will not build. Second of all learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you could step through the code line by line and see what's happening, and be able to monitor variables and their values.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the code builds perfectly . i agree it was my mistake to use wrong param `i` instead of `j`.and thanks i will be using debugger from now onwards

Comment: Once you fix the compilation error, it *does* sort that particular input, but it doesn't sort `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: @molbdnilo can you please explain a bit

Comment: @JoachimPileborg got it it was extra bracket . fixed it now

Comment: @molbdnilo it sorts {3,2,1}

Comment: @anekix The program you posted "sorts" `{1,2,3}` into `2 3 1`; [look here](http://ideone.com/XlOary). With the input you posted, it produces the correct output, despite your claim that it doesn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo that the wrong version of program . use the corrected version which was suggestes by others .

Comment: @anekix You should post the code that you're actually running and not a fantasy version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124135/discussion-between-anekix-and-molbdnilo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test you are using `i` while instead most probably you wanted to use `j` (as `i` is constant in that loop).

Answer (score 0):

A compiling and properly working code for sorting the vector in increasing order.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>


void bubble_sort(std::vector<int> &v){
    for( int i = 0; i < (v.size() - 1); i++){
        for( int j = 0; j < (v.size() - 1 - i) ; j++){
            if ( v[j] > v[j+1] ){
                std::swap(v[j], v[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }

}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v = {1,9,8,7,6,5,3,2};
    bubble_sort(v);

    for(auto &e : v){
        std::cout<<e<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You were trying to swap between ith index only. there was a problem.**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
void bubble_sort(std::vector<int> &v){
    for( int i = 0; i < (v.size() - 1); i++){
        for( int j = 0; j < (v.size() -1 - i) ; j++){
            if(v[j] > v[j+1]){
                std::swap(v[j], v[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    std::vector<int> v = {1,9,8,7,6,5,3,2};
    bubble_sort(v);
    for(auto &e : v){
        std::cout<<e<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you sorting in decreasing order. If nothing is given, sort means increasing order by default.

Comment: yup! I did mistake I fixed this. Thanks.